# Inline styles for tables in ReactJS/JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

Hi I'm having trouble adding inline styling to table components in React. Basically what I'm trying to do is so that the table header/cells are divided equally spacing so I'm adding `width: '50%'` styling to make this work. I added in the console and it works, but when I return to add it in my code, it doesn't.

I tried adding it to anything just to see if it work and it doesn't. Is there something I'm missing?

**What it looks like:**

[image: What it looks like]

**What I want it to look like (after adding width styling to console):**
[image: Width 50%]

**JSX**:

```
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr styles={{width: '50%'}}>
                                <th styles={{width: '50%'}}>Hello</th>
                                <th styles={{width: '50%'}}>World</th>                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {(data.length == 0)&&           
                                <tr>
                                    <td>I'm</td>
                                    <td>Sam</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Change 'styles' to 'style'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

> Change 'styles' to 'style' – cidicles

Usually plural styles is the convention people use when passing a variable to another component, while singular style is the keyword that jsx-html tags will receive to inline the css.

Other answers recommend adding styles to html tags directly in the css. While adding styles on html tags directly without using classes may work it is worth it to note that it may not scale well This will require more work on us to come back and maintain/update the original code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `table-layout: fixed; width: 100%` on the table to force equal column widths:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table tr th {
  text-align: left;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
                    <table className="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style={{width: '50%'}}>
                                <th style={{width: '50%'}}>Hello</th>
                                <th style={{width: '50%'}}>World</th>                                
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody        
                                <tr>
                                    <td>I'm</td>
                                    <td>Sam</td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Your `width: 50%` isn't working most likely because your parent `.table` doesn't have a width set. You can try adding `width: 100%` to the table and then your `50%` might work.

**EDIT**
As other users have mentioned, change `styles` to `style` as well.